# php update query not updating data (php/mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple update query thats built by the page, code is as follows.

```
<?php if ($resultADS->num_rows > 0) {
                    // output data of each row
                    while($rowADS = $resultADS->fetch_assoc()) {
                        //Reformat date to yyyy-mm-dd
                        $phpdate = strtotime( $rowADS['Assigned_Date_Sales'] );
                        $mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d', $phpdate );
                        
                        echo "ID: " . $rowADS['ID'] . " -  " . $rowADS['Assigned_Date_Sales'] . " New Date: ". $mysqldate . "<br>";
                    
                        $sqlADSupdate = "UPDATE customer_migration_details SET Assigned_Date_Sales_New = '" . $mysqldate . "' WHERE ID ='" . $rowADS['ID'] . "'<br>";
                        echo $sqlADSupdate;
                        $result = $conn->query($sqlADSupdate);
                        echo  "Updated Assigned Sales Date: " . $rowADS['Assigned_Date_Sales_New'] . "<br><br>";
                    
                    }
                }
                ?>
```

[Click here to see how the code outputs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKXA9.png)

The only problem is. its not updating the field in question.

Any ideas

Comment: Running the database update will not automatically be reflected in the values of `$rowADS`.  These will be the values from when the select was run.

Comment: can you confirm that database isnt updating? have you checked the database?

Comment: I'm drawing a blank here. each query is writing it self correctly, so why is the update not just running each time during the "while($rowADS = $resultADS->fetch_assoc()) {"

Comment: yeah the up Updated Assigned Sales Date: 0000-00-00 is from Assigned_Date_Sales_New field which isthe field im trying to update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please tell why are you using break tag at the end of the query? According to me your query should be:

```
$sqlADSupdate = "UPDATE customer_migration_details SET Assigned_Date_Sales_New = '" . $mysqldate . "' WHERE ID ='" . $rowADS['ID'] . "'";
```

Due to the inadequate query, it is not updating the table.

Comment: Amazing! got completely confused when it wouldn't work. How did i not see that. thank you very much lol

Comment: @DrewBurston No issue! A lot of coding makes everybody confused..